# how to convert NSinteger to String

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to convet int to string in objective c how to do that.

my code.

```
for (i=0; i<=200; i=i+10) {
    // here i want to convet the value of i into string how to do this 

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i have another string variable named myWord I want to assign i value to it.......

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableString *myWord = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<=200; i=i+10) {
    [myWord appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    //...
}
//do something with myWord...
[myWord release];
```

`NSInteger` is simply a `typedef` to the `int` or `long` data types  on 32/64-bit systems.

Comment: n13's answer below is the modern variant and far more elegant

Answer (score 14):

```
NSInteger n = 13;
NSString string = @(n).stringValue;
```

Reference see Objective-C literals - literals remove lots of ugly boilerplate code cluttering up your codebase: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Cool, thanks for introducing me to the easy way with the new syntax

Comment: This is actually slower and less memory efficient since you create an instance of `NSNumber` every time you wish to get a string value.

Did a benchmark with 1000000 iterations and got `0.924962` seconds with the `NSNumber` approach and got `0.668426` seconds using the `stringWithFormat` approach. This is just a consideration if you'd be using it in a huge loop.

Comment: ^ Interesting benchmark, but I'd have expected it to perform worse. A 30% difference is not that much. Obviously, don't do this if you're converting thousands or tens of thousand of numbers to String. Huge loop of number to String conversion sounds like bad code to me, no matter how you do the conversion.

Comment: Much better solution, thank you. This is also cross-compatible with 32- and 64-bit, and futureproof for any other format string weirdness!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to declare myWord out of the loop as NSMutableString.